# Updating Values of a Column from one Table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:-

Source Table: `ACT_DT` with columns (`CUST_NAME, ACC_TYPE, CUST_STAT, SB_ACT_DT`);

Target Table: `ORG_DT` with columns (`CUST_NAME, ACC_TYPE, CUST_STAT, SB_ACT_DT`);

The column `SB_ACT_DT` in the Target table has all null values. I need to update that column with the values of same column as in source table. The condition to be checked are:

```
ACC_TYPE='Billing' and CUST_STAT='Active'.
```

The Target table has to be updated only if the above conditions are found true.

How can I do it? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No.. I am new to SQL programming

Comment: if you wants the update query for target table..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Update table using Join

```
UPDATE ORG_DT o
JOIN ACT_DT a
ON o.CUST_NAME=a.CUST_NAME
   AND
  o.ACC_TYPE=a.ACC_TYPE
   AND
  o.CUST_STAT=a.CUST_STAT   
SET o.SB_ACT_DT = a.SB_ACT_DT
WHERE a.ACC_TYPE='Billing' AND a.CUST_STAT='Active'
```

Comment: Hello Hasan, how can I do the same using cursor if records are more in number?